# All colors list in lazarus

Tags: image, colors, lazarus

How many colors are in lazarus? I know about standard colors (clBlack, clGreen, clAqua, clYellow, etc.), but I want to know all colors, because when I want specifically color, I haven't it. And can I mix colors?

That picture I want to make:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6EZ1.jpg

And that picture I made:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/myAGK.jpg

And when you know website with color list, you can send it here.

Comment: The colors are unsigned integers with RGB(A) values. The named constants just predefine some common ones.

Comment: http://wiki.freepascal.org/Colors gives an overview of colour handling in the LCL.

Answer (score 1):

When you click the color property in the Object Inspector, you'll get a `...` button on the right. Then you can enter the color pretty much you want.